# Resources closed but sonarlint still showing resource not closed

Tags: java, io, sonarlint

I have defined Output stream like below 
`OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(file);`

Tried to close the resource like below

```
if(os != null) {
    try {
       os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

Still sonarlint showing "Use try-with-resources or close this "FileOutputStream" in a "finally" clause."

Comment: Please add the complete block of code. The Sonar rule could be a false positive for different reasons, like open in one method and close in another

Comment: @Dubas I am doing all operations in single method

Comment: is the above code is in finally block?

Comment: @karthikeyan Yes closing part was declared in finally block

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it with sonarlint on intellij. are you using eclipse?

Comment: @karthikeyan i am trying this in intellij only

Comment: PLease check [this gif](https://i.imgur.com/YxYQgib.gif) and check you have similar code.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing the operations in the same method it's important to put the close in a finally statement of a try that envolves the open part of the stream. This ensures that in case of failure (Exception) the stream is allways closed if required

Bad sonar code:

```
OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(file);

... // your code operations with os

// If something is going really bad here and ends in exception the
// stream will never be closed

if(os != null) {
    try {
       os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Better code:

```
OutputStream os = null;
try{
    os = new FileOutputStream(file);

    ... // your code operations with os

} finally{
    // The stream is allways closed at the end of the method execution
    if(os != null) {
        try {
           os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
 }
```

The best code (in case of Java 1.7 or upper)

```
try (OutputStream  os = new FileOutputStream(file)){

  ... // your code operations with os

  // The stream is allways closed at the end of the try block
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. the try with resources is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. You do not do a close when using try with resources, that is automatically handled... i.e.

> "The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed
>   at the end of the statement."

```
try( OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(file) ) {
    ....
}
```

Any resources declared within the brackets are closed automatically once the program flow has completed whether an exception is thrown or not..

Examples here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html